# Java The method in the type Stub is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, web-services, jsp

I know that this is yet another topic with similar subject, but i've searched stackoverflow and i could not find answer to my problem.
The situation is as follows:
I have a webservice lets call it testservice with many methods. Recently i had to add another one so i did:

```
public int addPayments_p24(String sessionId, int pos_id, String amount, String currency, String title, String client, String address, String postal, String city, String country, String email, String language, String p24_sign) throws Exception {
     int last_inserted_id=0;
try {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    int timestamp = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
    statement = connection
                .prepareStatement(
                        "Insert into p24_strefa(pos_id,session_id,amount,currency,title,client,address,postal,city,country,email,language,p24_sign,timestamp)" +
                                "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        statement.setInt(1, pos_id);
        statement.setString(2, sessionId);
        statement.setString(3, amount);
        statement.setString(4, currency);
        statement.setString(5, title);
        statement.setString(6, client);
        statement.setString(7, address);
        statement.setString(8, postal);
        statement.setString(9, city);
        statement.setString(10, country);
        statement.setString(11, email);
        statement.setString(12, language);
        statement.setString(13, p24_sign);
        statement.setInt(14, timestamp);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
            if(rs.next())
            {
              last_inserted_id  = rs.getInt(1);
            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        _log.error("addpayments_p24", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {
        dispose();
    }

    return last_inserted_id;
}
```

Then i tried to call this method from jsp file like this:

```
String sessionId = request.getParameter( "p24_session_id" );
String amount =  request.getParameter( "p24_amount" );
String currencys = request.getParameter("p24_currency");
String title = request.getParameter("p24_description");
String client = request.getParameter("p24_client");
String address = request.getParameter("p24_address");
String postal = request.getParameter("p24_zip");
String city = request.getParameter("p24_city");
String country = request.getParameter("p24_country");
String email = request.getParameter("p24_email");
String language = request.getParameter("p24_language");
String sign = get_sign_str(sessionId,amount,currencys);
int pos_id = 2414;
int testResponse;
    try {
        if (test== null) {
        inittest();
    }
    testResponse = test.addPayments_p24("test",2,"test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test");
    } 
    catch (testWebServicesExceptionException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The connection to webservice is done by this function:

```
private static testWebServicesStub test;
 private synchronized void inittest() throws AxisFault {
        if (test == null) {
            String testWebServicesEndpoint = Settings
                    .gettestWebServicesEndpoint();
            test= new testWebServicesStub(testWebServicesEndpoint);
        }
    }
```

As you can see i use Axis2.
And ofcourse i got the error:

```
The method addPayments_p24(AddPayments_p24) in the type TestWebServicesStub is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)
```

I sit at this problem for a third day now and I just can't figure it out. If anyone have any idea what's going on...

I almost forgot app is run on a apache-tomcat 7.0.34 if that changes anything but i've already tested on another version.
Ofcourse everything was compiled multiple times, after compilation I even decompiled everything to check if variable types are correct and of course they were...

Comment: Can you post the server side code for `addPayments_p24`? What framework are you using for the web service client? Can you also post the code just before you call your web service.

Comment: Is it possible that java returns that error because of the different error in webservice function body?

Comment: To test if the problem is on the server or the client you can use some REST client and make requests directly to the web service to find out on which end the problem lies. Either you can use browser plugins such as Postman (chrome) or Poster (Firefox) or a stand alone client such as SoapUI

Comment: I used a postman and when i tried to send the request to soap server i got: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>13</faultstring>
            <detail />
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use web services for a while, so I'm not sure about this, but, it seems that you are mixing between two methods just like the error suggests, it happens that you are calling the method

`addPayments_p24(String, int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)`

which is not present in the client, neither it's interface (at least the visible scope of the call). the method present in the scope of the call (in the client) is `addPayments_p24(AddPayments_p24)`, so you need to instantiate an object AddPayments_p24 probably with the arguments you wanted `(String, int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)`  , not sure about this but it seems to be true.

Comment: ahh those autogenerated wsdl, i do not even have such object created, but i'll try that, it makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove "throw ex;" and "throws Exception" from addPayments_p24.